# Chef - admin permissions

Tags: chef-infra, permission-denied, winrm

I'd like to get work chef client. All these next command works perfectly on windows 8, but i have troubles with windows 7.

I have got fresh install of win7, so firstly I setup winrm by these commands:

```
call winrm quickconfig
call winrm set winrm/config/service/auth @{Basic="true"}
call winrm set winrm/config/service @{AllowUnencrypted="true"}
call winrm set winrm/config @{MaxTimeoutms="3000000"}
```

after that i bootstrap this node by knife-windows:

```
knife bootstrap windows winrm {IP} --winrm-user {username} --winrm-password {password} --node-name {nodename}
```

now i can see different behaviour between win7/win8 because it fails at downloading chef-client by cscript - permission denied - but install it by powershell.

When i want to install something  - firefox, chocolatey - recipes from chef supermarket it fails with permission denied.

```
knife node run_list set {node_name} firefox
```

and then run

```
knife winrm {IP} chef-client --manual-list --winrm-user {username} --winrm-password {password}
```

and it fails

if i run `chef-client` on that win7 from cmd as admin it finish successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I had similiar problems running Vagrant with Chef on Windows 7 station.

Firstly, I did this set of commands:

```
winrm quickconfig -q
winrm set winrm/config/winrs @{MaxMemoryPerShellMB="512"}
winrm set winrm/config @{MaxTimeoutms="1800000"}
winrm set winrm/config/service @{AllowUnencrypted="true"}
winrm set winrm/config/service/auth @{Basic="true"}
sc config WinRM start= auto
```

Try as well disable (or set up to allow Chef etc.) Windows Firewall. 
If you are running this as Vagrant machine, you have also to install Guest Additions on VBox, disable UAC.

It is important that Chef needs permissions to create/delete/update objects - and it will fail, if they are not granted. I've found [here](https://github.com/chef/chef-dk/issues/109) information, that you could try disable UAC and/or change User Account Policies in your Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I have completely disabled UAC and firewall.
I this this is out of the Virtualbox because i have tried this on physical PC with win 7 too - stil not working.

I can normally create cookbook without any errors.

I don't know where is a mistake. I have tried many win 7 versions and vitualbox/my PC/friend's PC with win 7 but it can't works.

//EDIT
I tried install something (firefox) using

```
knife winrm -m {IP} -x {user} "chocolatey install --force firefox -y"
```

and there is the same problem with admin privilegies

if I run the chocolatey command from admin powershell it run without errors

So I think problem is either in knife-winrm (but it works with win8) or in win7 configuration - (winrm or something magic)

Answer (score 0):

This belongs in a comment but I don't have that ability so forgive me.

Is it possible that your powershell policy is too constrictive for chef to run? Try manually opening powershell as admin and entering

```
Get-ExecutionPolicy
```

Both Chef and Chocolatey use powershell to work their magic on windows machines. Also, in Chef 12.4.0 and later it is expected that you have powershell v5 installed, and I've experienced some strangeness around x86 powershell being used instead of x64 if you are on powershell 4 or earlier. You might try locking to Chef-client version 12.3.0 by adding the following to your bootstrap command

```
--bootstrap-version 12.3.0
```

I hope some of this helps at least. If the execution policy is the issue you can set it to a less restrictive level with

```
--Set-ExecutionPolicy
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, you are a genious. Firstly I tried get-executionpolicy but there was unrestricted so it was OK. But I tried install powershell 4 and then everything works. Thank you very much again.

Comment: Happy to help. Keep whipping up awesome!